# Maximum Vin on load switch ICs

Tags: voltage, power, datasheet, load, maximum-ratings

I'm trying to determine whether the absolute maximum rating for Vin on load switch ICs applies for when the switch is both open and closed.

When the switch is closed, it makes absolute sense to me that you should not try to have Vin above this rating. But what about when Vin is open? Isn't the voltage just floating then? Could I theoretically have the voltage above the datasheet's absolute maximum for Vin?

I'm trying to understand whether why or why this isn't possible in a load switch IC. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vin will be measured with respect to some other pin. Usually, this pin will be the Ground pin, the 0v reference, for the power supplies and the logic control. The switch input must not be more than Vin(max) voltage difference from this pin. Too much voltage difference can over-stress the internal structures and break the IC. If there's a Vin(max) on the data sheet, it's there for a reason.

Often, a data sheet will quote several maximums, so maximum switch current, maximum voltage under this condition, maximum voltage under that condition, maximum power dissipation etc. *All* limits have to be respected, or you're likely to break the IC.